# For a function $f = f(t,x)$, how is the space $C^0([0,T];(S'(\mathbb R^d))^n)$ defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, distribution-theory

I'm reading "Fourier Analysis and non-linear Partial Differential Equations" from H. Bahouri and they use a notation which is unknown to me.

If $(t,x) \in \mathbb [0,T] \times \mathbb R^d$, $A([0,T],\mathbb R)$ is any space of functions from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb R$ in the variable $t$, such as $C^0([0,T],\mathbb R)$, and $B(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^n)$ is any normed space of functions from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R^n$ in the variable $x$, such as $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^n)$, I deduced that $A([0,T];B(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^n))$ would be the space
$$A([0,T];B(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^n)) = \{f : [0,T] \times \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R^n \mid f(t,x) \in B(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^n) \ \forall t, \ ||f(t,\cdot )||_B \in A([0,T],\mathbb R)\}$$

For $B$ a locally convex topological vector space, such as $S(\mathbb R^d)$, I guess we can make the same definition but with semi-norms.

However, they also use this notation with $B$ being some distribution space such as $(S'(\mathbb R^d))^n$ (a vector of $n$ tempered distributions). In this case, I cannot make sense of, say, the space $C^0([0,T];(S'(\mathbb R^d))^n)$ or $L^1([0,T];(S'(\mathbb R^d))^n)$ .

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: To clear out any misunderstanding about the notation, correct me if I am wrong : $C^0$ refers to continuous functions,  $B$ to bounded continuous function, $L^\infty$ to measurable essentially bounded functions (modulo equality a.e.), $\mathcal S$ is the Schwartz space and $\mathcal S'$ its topological dual, the space of tempered distributions.  I am not sure what $A$ is supposed to mean though.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are just notations I chose to denote a general space of functions. It could be $L^1$, $C^0$, $S$ or anything. I just wanted to have a general statement. As for $C^0$, $L^{\infty}$, $S$ and $S'$, you are correct about their meaning.

Answer (score 4):

For $\mathcal C^0(X,Y)$ to make sense, you need $X$ and $Y$ to be equipped with a topology. $X = [0,T]$ has a standard topology, and so does any normed vector space.

For $\mathcal C^0([0,T],A(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^n))$ to make sense, you need to choose a topology for $A(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^n)$. One example is $A = C^0_b$ the space of bounded continuous function, which is a normed vector space (actually a Banach space) when equipped with the supremum norm :
$$\|f\|_{C^0_b} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R^d} \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb R^n}$$

This means that $C^0([0,T], \mathcal C^0_b(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^n))$ is the space of functions $f:[0,T]\to B(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^n)$ which are continuous, ie for each $t\in [0,T]$, $f(t)$ is a bounded continuous function $f(t): x\in \mathbb R^d\mapsto  f(t)(x)\in \mathbb R^n$ and that for each $t\in [0,T]$ and $\epsilon >0$, there is some $\eta>0$ such that if $t'\in [0,T]$ and $|t'-t| < \eta$, then :
$$\|f(t) - f(t')\|_{B(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^n)} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R^d}\| f(t)(x) - f(t')(x)\|_{\mathbb R^n} \leq \epsilon$$
This would work in exactly the same way for $A = L^p$ (with $p\in [1,\infty])$ or many other functional Banach spaces.

For $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S'$, the situation is a bit more complicated, since they are not normed vector space. The [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ is also a topological vector space (specifically a Fréchet space). The space of tempered distributions $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$ is its topological dual, and is can be equipped with different topologies, derived from that of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$, most notably the [strong dual topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_dual_space) and the [weak-$*$-topology](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Weak-StarTopology.html). Once one of those is chosen, $\mathcal C^0([0,T]; \mathcal S'(\mathbb R))$ is just the space of continuous function from $[0,T]$ to $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: This makes sense for $C^0$, but they also use $L^1([0,T];S'(\mathbb R))$, which we cannot make sense using only a topology on $S'(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I am not sure how to make sense of this $L^1$ space. The measurability condition *could* use the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $\mathcal S'$ (but I am not sure this is how it is done in practice). The integrability condition could be requiring that the semi-norms of the functions are all integrable (but again, I am not sure about this). I think this could be the object of another more specific question

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, those kind of spaces are defined as follows :

1. If $(X, ||\cdot ||_X)$ is a Banach space and $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, then $L^p(\Omega; X)$ is the set of [Bochner measurable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_measurable_function) $u : \Omega \rightarrow X$ such that the following Lebesgue integral is finite : $$\int_{\Omega} ||u(y)||_X^p \ dy < \infty$$
2. If $\Phi$ is a [Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) and $I \subset \mathbb R$ is an open interval, then $C^k(I;\Phi)$ is the space of functions $u : I \rightarrow \Phi$ that are $k$-times continuously [differentiable in a Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_in_Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces). Continuity is in the sense of the topology and differentiability is in the sense of the [Gateau derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative), i.e.
   $$u'(t) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{u(t+h)-u(t)}{h}$$
   if the limit exists in the space $\Phi$.
   Note that if $u \in C^k(I;\Phi)$, then for each continuous semi-norm $\rho : \Phi \rightarrow \mathbb R$, we have $\rho \circ u : I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ belongs to $C^k(I)$ thanks to the reverse triangle inequality. However, the converse is not true.
3. For a Frechet space $\Phi$, with dual $\Phi'$ endowed with the weak topology, and $I \subset \mathbb R$ is an open interval, then $C^k(I;\Phi')$ is the space of functions $u : I \rightarrow \Phi'$ such that for each test function $\phi \in \Phi$, the function $u(\cdot) \phi : I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ belongs to $C^k(I)$. With this definition, it is a consequence of Banach-Steinhaus that $u$ is differentiable in a weak sense, i.e. for each $t \in I$,
   $$u'(t) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{u(t+h) - u(t)}{h}$$
   converges in $\Phi'$ to an element $u'(t) \in \Phi'$ and $u' \in C^{k-1}(I;\Phi')$. For more details on this space, see Chapter 4 of "Elements de distributions et d'équations aux dérivées partielles" by Claude Zuily.
4. For a space of distributions such as $S'(\mathbb R^d)$, if $I \subset \mathbb R$ is an interval, I think that $L^1(I; S'(\mathbb R^d))$ is the space of functions $u : I \rightarrow S'(\mathbb R^d)$ such that for all test functions $\phi \in S(\mathbb R^{1+d})$ : $u(t)\phi(t) \in L^1(I)$. Maybe an argument involving Banach-Steinhaus can work and we might only need that for all test functions $\phi \in S(\mathbb R^d)$ : $u(t)\phi \in L^1(I)$. I've asked a question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182646/if-langle-ut-phi-rangle-in-l1-forall-phi-in-s-bbb-rd-does-la).

Comment: I understand the setting that you are trying to build. I have asked myself an analogous question some months ago (like, how to define $L^1(I; S'(\mathbb R^d))$ and what if I want to integrate $u(t)$?). Unfortunately, I don't have any idea about references on something analogous to the Bochner spaces but for Frechet spaces instead of Banach spaces. I know about this series of lectures on youtube about Bochner spaces (and more): https://youtu.be/De36jbpMNrA I think there also was a website with the lecture notes. I could provide them to you in some way if you are interested

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thank you for your comment. I don't understand why authors don't bother defining clearly those spaces. That being said, I'm interested in the lecture notes ! Sadly, the link in the youtube video does not work anymore. I've created a chat room where you can provide me some link : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127174/pde-related-discussion