# If $\langle u(t), \phi \rangle \in L^1\ \forall \phi \in S(\Bbb R^d)$, does $\langle u(t), \phi(t) \rangle \in L^1\ \forall \phi \in S(\Bbb R^{1+d})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $S(\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of [Schwartz functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) and $S'(\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of [tempered distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) (the continuous linear functionals from $S(\mathbb R^d)$ to $\mathbb R$) endowed with the weak topology.

Assume that $I \subset \mathbb R$ is a compact interval and that $u : I \rightarrow S'(\mathbb R^d)$ is a family of tempered distributions such that
$$\langle u(t), \phi \rangle \in L^1(I) \ \forall \phi \in S(\mathbb R^d)$$

Does it follow that $\langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle \in L^1(I) \ \forall \phi \in S(\mathbb R^{1+d})$ ?

I've already asked this [question in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395060/does-f-in-l10-t-s-mathbb-rn-define-a-1n-dimensional-distributi), but I've got no answer so far. This question is also related to this [other question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166766/for-a-function-f-ft-x-how-is-the-space-c00-ts-mathbb-rdn-d/4166809?noredirect=1#comment8636699_4166809).

I'm asking this question because it is proved in Chapter 4 of "Eléments de distributions et d'équations aux dérivées partielles" by Claude Zuily that if

$$\langle u(t), \phi \rangle \in C^0(I) \ \forall \phi \in S(\mathbb R^d)$$

then $\langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle \in C^0(I) \ \forall \phi \in S(\mathbb R^{1+d})$ as well. It is a consequence of Banach-Steinhaus. For the sake of completeness, I'm rewriting the proof for the $C^0$ case below.

I was wondering if we can do something similar for $L^1$ space. Any reference is welcomed.

One last remark : Observe that $\langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle$ is always the pointwise limit of $L^1(I)$ functions, hence it is Lebesgue measurable. Indeed, if $\phi(t,x) = a(t)b(x)$ for $a \in S(\mathbb R)$, $b \in S(\mathbb R^d)$, then

$$\langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle = \langle u(t), b \rangle a(t) \in L^1(I)$$

For a general $\phi(t,x)$, it can be shown (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63416/tensor-products-of-functions-generate-dense-subspace) for example) that it is the limit in $S(\mathbb R^{1+d}$) of a sequence $\phi_n(t,x)$, where each $\phi_n$ is a finite linear combination of elements of the form $a(t)b(x)$, $a \in S(\mathbb R)$, $b \in S(\mathbb R^d)$.

---

**Proof of Claude Zuily for the $C^0$ case** :

We prove continuity of $\langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle$ at $t_0 \in I$. Let $(t_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset I$ converge to $t_0$. We define $u_j := u(t_j)$ and $\phi_j := \phi(t_j, \cdot)$. By assumption, $u_j$ converges to $u(t_0)$ in $S'(\mathbb R^d)$. In particular
$$\sup_{j \in \mathbb N} | \langle u_j, \psi \rangle | < +\infty \ \forall \psi \in S(\mathbb R^d)$$
Banach-Steinhaus theorem implies that there exists a continuous semi-norm $\rho : S(\mathbb R^d) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
$$| \langle u_j, \psi \rangle | \leq \rho(\psi) \ \forall j \in \mathbb N \ \forall \psi \in S(\mathbb R^d)$$
Moreover, it is easy to check that $\phi_j$ converges to $\phi(t_0, \cdot)$ in $S(\mathbb R^d)$.

Hence,
$$| \langle u_j, \phi_j \rangle - \langle u(t_0), \phi(t_0, \cdot) \rangle | \leq | \langle u_j, \phi_j - \phi(t_0, \cdot) \rangle | +  | \langle u_j, \phi(t_0, \cdot) \rangle - \langle u(t_0), \phi(t_0, \cdot) \rangle| $$

and everything goes to zero as $j \to +\infty$.

Comment: The idea that I have is to try to establish that the distributions $u(t)$ all share the same order (or lower) for almost every $t$. If you take distributions of arbitrary order in $u(t)$, you can have bad things I think, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352392/order-of-growth-of-derivatives-at-given-x?rq=1  Then, if this is true, maybe there is some hope